# Liferay searchContext search by AssetTags and Keywords

Tags: search, liferay, faceted-search

I'm trying to implement custom search portlet through AssetEntries. Currently AssetEntryQuery doesn't allow to search with keywords. I'm trying to search through FacetedSearcher. Search by keywords seems to be ok. But when I'm trying to search by AssetTagNames

```
searchContext.setAssetTagNames(assetTagNames)
```

it doesn't work at all. 
Here's my piece of code

```
 SearchContext searchContext = new SearchContext();
         Facet assetEntriesFacet = new AssetEntriesFacet(searchContext);
         assetEntriesFacet.setStatic(true);
         searchContext.addFacet(assetEntriesFacet);

         /*MultiValueFacet multiValueFacet=new MultiValueFacet(searchContext);
         multiValueFacet.setFieldName("assetTagNames");
         multiValueFacet.setStatic(false);
         searchContext.addFacet(multiValueFacet);*/

       searchContext.setCompanyId(themeDisplay.getCompanyId());
       String []assetTagNames=new String[1];
        assetTagNames[0]=  assetTagName;
        searchContext.setAssetTagNames(assetTagNames);
        searchContext.setKeywords(keywords);
        String[] entryClassName = {JournalArticle.class.getName()};
        searchContext.setEntryClassNames(entryClassName);

        Indexer indexer = FacetedSearcher.getInstance();
       // searchContext.setAndSearch(true);
        Hits hits = indexer.search(searchContext);
        System.out.println("Hits: " + hits.getLength());
```

Resulted query for request 
searchKeyword: key1key1
assetTagName: sometag

```
+(+(companyId:1) +((+(entryClassName:com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle) +(status:0)))) +(assetCategoryTitles:*key1key1* assetCategoryTitles_en_US:*key1key1* assetTagNames:*key1key1* comments:key1key1 content:key1key1 description:key1key1 properties:key1key1 title:key1key1 url:key1key1 userName:*key1key1* classPK:key1key1 content_en_US:key1key1 description_en_US:key1key1 entryClassPK:key1key1 title_en_US:key1key1 type:key1key1)
```

As you see AssetTag isn't applied to the query.
I've already tried to set it through

```
searchContext.setAttribute("assetTagNames",assetTagName);
```

and commented MultiValueFacet code but wih no result.
For further i need to search by dateRange and Categories. Has anybody any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately solved this.

If you'd like to search through tags you've to use a separate facet for this, e.g.

```
        MultiValueFacet assetTagsFacet = new MultiValueFacet(searchContext);
        assetTagsFacet.setFieldName(Field.ASSET_TAG_NAMES);
        searchContext.addFacet(assetTagsFacet);
```

Also use `searchContext.setAttribute("assetTagNames", assetTagName);` instead of `searchContext.setAssetTagNames(assetTagName);`

For searching through Categories the same thing:

```
        MultiValueFacet assetCategoriesFacet = new MultiValueFacet(searchContext);
        assetCategoriesFacet.setFieldName("assetCategoryTitles");
        searchContext.addFacet(assetCategoriesFacet);
        searchContext.setAttribute("assetCategoryTitles", assetCategoryName);
```

Also i wanted to search by custom type of JournalArticle, Ive created facet for this, but got "type" twice in query. As a solution i used MultiValueFacet instead of AssetEntriesFacet during setting entryClassName

```
    MultiValueFacet assetEntriesFacet = new MultiValueFacet(searchContext);
    assetEntriesFacet.setFieldName("entryClassName");
    searchContext.setAttribute("entryClassName",JournalArticle.class.getName());
    searchContext.addFacet(assetEntriesFacet);
```